# Why contract event data is undefined on a testnet but not in a local node?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, ethers.js

I've created the following Solidity contract that emits an event:

[image]

And in my front-end JS code I'm using ethers.js and reading the data from the event with `event.args[2]` (line 76):

[image]

When I use a Hardhat local node the `event.args[2]` has what I'm expecting.

However `event.args` is undefined when I use the contract deployed on a Polygon Mumbai testnet node with Alchemy.com.

[image]

I appreciate any help or guidance with this error I'm facing, let me know if I should share any other info.
Cheers.

Comment: What is the contract address on Polygon Mumbai? Can you check that you're passing the correct address on the testnet (most likely is different than on the local node)?

Comment: The contract address deployed on Mumbai is: 0x67545d5b8cc9a8864ff593d4140e2264209133df
This is my latest contract call to the Mint Token method: https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0xd65a153ce1c4fdf0e44811f0b9d31c46213c64c186d24dd48906c914893e2226 
I have a script that updates the contract address on my web app every time I run a deployment, and it seems to be working correctly.
BTW, can you read the contract using the address I shared? I thought this was something that could be done on polygonscan, but I can't seem to be able to...